# Why didn't Figment and Dreamfinder return to Earth?

Tags: marvel, figment

I just finished the comic series [*Figment*](http://marvel.com/comics/series/18980/figment_2014_-_present), which tells the story of Figment and Dreamfinder's first journey. In the final issue, they confront the Articulate Army led by The Singular and draw them into a portal.

But afterwards, the duo don't even consider imagining up a portal to go back to Earth. I would think they would want to make sure that everyone is okay, or at least have a nice home-cooked meal with Dreamfinder's mother, as he mentions at the beginning of the issue.

I get that they want to explore other worlds, but why didn't Dreamfinder and Figment even consider returning to Earth?